# Does HttpClient use different SecurityProtocol in Windows Service vs ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-services, dotnet-httpclient

I have Windows Service and ASP.NET application. Both the applications are sharing the same  .Net Library that is internally using `HttpClient` class to make GET and POST request.

When Windows Service is making the GET call via shared library, then i dont get any exception. However when ASP.NET make the GET call via the same shared library i am getting the following exception.

> Timestamp: 11/1/2017 4:55:23 PM
>
> Message: Message: One or more errors occurred. Type:
>   AggregateException Stack Trace:    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   MyCompany.SharedLib.CFGetRequest(String params, Int32 attempt)    at
>   MyCompany.SharedLib.Pause(String apiKey, Int32 jobId)    at
>   MyCompany.Domain.Services.LabDomainService.Pause(Detail detail, String
>   apiKey) in d:\Jenkins\XXXXXX.cs:line 189    at
>   MyCompany.Domain.Services.LabDomainService.Pause(Int32 id) in
>   d:\Jenkins\XXXXXX.cs:line 101    at
>   MyCompany.UI.Controllers.HomeController.Pause(Int32 id) in
>   d:\Jenkins\XXXXX:line 135    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase
>   , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> Inner Exception Message:  An error occurred while sending the request.
>   Type: HttpRequestException Inner Exception Stack Trace:
>
> Inner Exception Message:  The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send. Type: WebException Inner
>   Exception Stack Trace:     at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)
>
> Inner Exception Message:  Authentication failed because the remote
>   party has closed the transport stream. Type: IOException Inner
>   Exception Stack Trace:     at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>
> Category: General
>
> Priority: -1
>
> EventId: 0
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Title:
>
> Machine: WIN-T49H73AEU41
>
> App Domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-3-131540289107739161
>
> ProcessId: 26596
>
> Process Name: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>
> Thread Name:
>
> Win32 ThreadId:30164

**Background**
We started getting this exception recently in both the applications, so based on research we update the Target framework from `4.5` to `4.6.2` so applications can use TLS1.2 version. After upgrading the target framework windows service is working fine however ASP.NET application is still throws above exception

Does `HttpClient` use different default `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` in Widows Service vs in ASP.NET

Comment: Could it be related to a firewall setting/rule?

Comment: but that should apply to both applications since they both are running on the same server

Comment: btw i solved the issue by explicitly setting `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;` in shared library

Comment: Firewall rules can be applied on the ip, port, and/or application level, so a service may function, but a client may not (or vice versa) if strict rules are in place.  As for the TLS setting, are you using SSL?

Comment: yes both client and API server has SSL